# Multiple aggregations on pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of data which is originally displayed like this:

[image]

I have created a pivot query:

```
SELECT  Ref,
        COALESCE([SALES],'N/A') AS [SALES],
        COALESCE([PURCHASING], 'N/A') AS [PURCHASING]

FROM

(SELECT Ref,
        Sub_Ref,
        Division

FROM dbo.Accounts_Download

WHERE Ref = 'MCA042G21AA'

) AS SourceTable

Pivot (MAX(Sub_Ref) For Division in ([SALES],[PURCHASING])) AS CvgPivot
```

to display the data like this:

[image]

However, I have been asked to add in a new field called Profit:

[image]

It doesn't seem to matter where I insert the SUM function in my pivot query. I keep coming back to the data being displayed like this:

[image]

Any help on how to use multiple aggregations in one pivot query would be much appreciated. As everything I'm doing is coming back to multiple rows. I'd really like the data to be displayed like this:

[image]

Comment: Please don't undo edits to your question. Tags do not belong in a question title, neither does fluff like "Thanks in advance".

Comment: Politeness is good. But the StackOverflow flavor or politeness is to help with making a good collection of Q/A pairs, according to best practices like [ask], which are targeted at making the donation of spare time of our users efficient and worthwile. Your kind of politenss is appropriate in discussion forums, but StackOverflow does not identify itself as one. As a question author, the politest thing you can do is to make a good question, react to feedback, give feedback on answers and finally (up-)vote and/or accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
     select ref,min(sales)SALES,min(purchasing) PURCHASING,sum(profit) profit from (
    SELECT  Ref,
    COALESCE([SALES],'N/A') AS [SALES],
    COALESCE([PURCHASING], 'N/A') AS [PURCHASING],profit

    FROM

    (SELECT Ref,
    Sub_Ref,
    Division,
    profit
    FROM Accounts_Download

    WHERE Ref = 'MCA042G21AA'

    ) AS SourceTable

    Pivot (MAX(Sub_Ref)  
    For Division in ([SALES],[PURCHASING])) AS CvgPivot) as a
    group by ref
```

check the link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=43951fbc18c43e502f12d1612cac64e3

Answer (score 0):

Also it could be done like this:

```
;WITH SourceTable 
AS (
    SELECT Ref,
    Sub_Ref,
    Division,
    Profit
    FROM Accounts_Download
    WHERE Ref = 'MCA042G21AA'
),

cte AS (
    SELECT  Ref, 
            Sub_ref, 
            Division, 
            SUM( Profit) OVER ( PARTITION BY Ref ORDER BY Ref, Sub_ref ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) Profit 
    FROM SourceTable
)

SELECT  Ref, 
        COALESCE( Sales, 'N/A') Sales, 
        COALESCE( Purchasing, 'N/A') Purchasing, 
        Profit 
FROM cte
PIVOT (
    MAX( Sub_ref) 
    FOR Division IN ( [SALES], [PURCHASING])
) AS CvgPivot
```

Basically, `PIVOT` groups your data by selected columns which are not presented in `PIVOT` i.e. `Ref`, `Profit`